# Existence of $L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ Function Defined via Functional Equation

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Perhaps, I'm reading the problem statement wrong, and it's not asking for existence, only uniqueness; but in any case...

> **Problem.** Let $g\in L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$, $\|g\|_{L^{1}}<1$. Prove that there is a unique $f\in L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ such that
>   $$f(x)+(f\ast g)(x)=e^{-|x|^{2}}, \quad x\in\mathbb{R}^{n} \enspace\text{a.e.}$$

The uniqueness isn't hard to show. Suppose such an $f\in L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ exists. Then taking Fourier transforms under the convention

$$\widehat{f}(\xi)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}f(x)e^{-2\pi i x\cdot\xi}dx,\quad\xi\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$$

we obtain

$$\widehat{f}(\xi)+\widehat{f}(\xi)\widehat{g}(\xi)=Ce^{-c|\xi|^{2}}$$

where $C,c$ are some constants that don't matter. Since $\|\widehat{g}\|_{\infty}\leq\|g\|_{L^{1}}<1$, $(1+\widehat{g}(\xi))^{-1}$ is a bounded, positive continuous function. Hence, we can write

$$\widehat{f}(\xi)=C\frac{e^{-c|\xi|^{2}}}{1+\widehat{g}(\xi)},\quad\forall \xi\in\mathbb{R}^{n} \tag{*}$$

Fourier inversion then completes the proof of uniqueness.

Regarding existence, since the RHS of * is rapidly decaying, we can take the inverse Fourier transform of both sides of * to obtain a $C_{0}$ $f$. And by approximating $g$ by Schwartz functions, we probably get by distribution theory that $f$ satisfies the functional equation (the convolution is well-defined since $f\in L^{\infty}$). But since the only regularity for $\widehat{f}$ is continuity, it's not clear to me that $f\in L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$. Any thoughts?

Comment: How do you conclude that $\|g\|_\infty \le \|g\|_1$? Also, I would interpret the 'there is' in the question as an existence question.

Comment: That was obviously a typo for $||\hat g||_\infty\le||g||_1$..

Comment: @copper.hat: I conclude it's a typo.

Comment: How do you know that $\hat{g}(\xi) \neq -1$?

Comment: @copper.hat: then $\|\widehat{g}(\xi)\|_{\infty}=1$, which contradicts that $\|\widehat{g}\|_{\infty}<1$. This is a special case of the Hausdorff-Young inequality.

Comment: @copper.hat Because $|-1|$ is not less than $1$.

Comment: My apologies, I was mixing up the $g$ and $\hat{g}$, I now see what you meant by a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Note that $$\frac{1}{1+\hat g}=1-\hat g+\hat g^2\dots.$$ Since $||g||_1<1$, the series $$h=-g+g*g-g*g*g...$$converges in $L^1$.

---

This is actually a special case of something about linear operators: If $||T||<1$ then $I-T$ is invertible. (Which is a special case of something about Banach algebras...)

Comment: Don't you need $|x|<1$ to conclude that ${ 1\over 1+x} = 1-x+...$?

Comment: @copper.hat Yes. And as we've established, $||\hat g||_\infty\le||g||_1<1$.

Comment: I need more caffeine...

Comment: Very nice, David. Thank you.

Comment: @NikQuine See minor edit for how I came up with that so fast - it's a very standard argument in some areas.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: I saw it; I am familiar with the argument.